Redis Server - Localhost on Windows 11
I want to host a Localhost Redis Server on my Windows Computer.
I want it like the Progamm "XAMPP" for Start this.
Have you found a Progamm for my Problem or you can an other idea? Please answer here.
(UP TO 220 Charcters)

I was having this particular problem and decided to fix it...
It requires Java (Tested with Java 12..but it should work down to java 8). But it should get you up and running for something simple.
Note: It's not complete, but it covers quite a bit of what redis can do, speaks RESP3, and is a reasonable toy deployment.
https://github.com/ZedrikCayne/gohorserace
